# Disable touchpad but keep buttons

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, xinput, libinput

I have a Thinkpad T440s, which, to my dismay, has a large touchpad that is just one clickable thing, and so the mouse buttons are in fact just designated areas on the touchpad.

I would much rather just use the trackpoint, but of course I need to be able to click.
Disabling the touchpad (with xinput using libinput) also disables the clickable areas.

Is there any way around it?

---

EDIT

So I just realized I can do the following:

- Set coordinate transformation matrix to

  > 0 0 0
  >
  > 0 0 0
  >
  > 0 0 1

  this way, moving the finger on the trackpad doesn't do anything.
- disable tapping

and then I basically have a touchpad which is good for nothing but scrolling and clicking.

But after a while I've noticed that the "buttons" do not even remotely feel the same as on e.g. the T500, and also the trackpoint is physically not as good.

Guess I'll have to ponder to which of the two options I'm more likely to get used to.

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy enough (without programming) way.

Comment: @Pilot6: That wouldn't be too bad, but see also my edit.

Comment: See [How to use trackpoint but keep touchpad disabled on Lenovo ThinkPad e531](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370505/how-to-use-trackpoint-but-keep-touchpad-disabled-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e531), maybe this works on yours too?