# Ubuntu 14.04 - Lenovo Ultrabook Touchpad Drag not working

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo, drag-and-drop

Suddenly I'm unable to drag and drop with the touchpad on my Lenovo U410. All the other features such as scroll, right click (two finger tap) and left click work. 
I'm using ubuntu 14.04 
I tried using touchpad-indicator to troubleshoot but that didn't work. 
How do I troubleshoot this drag and drop ? I can't even drag and select text.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here,
[Disable Mouse Movement in Tap Zones on Synaptics Trackpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250336/disable-mouse-movement-in-tap-zones-on-synaptics-trackpad)

and I used:

```
synclient AreaBottomEdge=4200
```

It worked perfectly fine with my laptop.