# Cannot use twofinger gesture on lenovo touchpad ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo

Cannot use twofinger on lenovo z5070 touchpad   ubuntu 14.04.

I also tried

[twofinger scroll on lenovo g50](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519696/twofinger-scroll-on-lenovo-g50)

[ALPS touchpad detected as PS/2, corrected with psmouse-dkms-alpsv7 but reset after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505633/alps-touchpad-detected-as-ps-2-corrected-with-psmouse-dkms-alpsv7-but-reset-aft)

[Ubuntu 14.04 - Lenovo Ultrabook Touchpad Drag not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520784/ubuntu-14-04-lenovo-ultrabook-touchpad-drag-not-working)

pointing devices

when I use command synclent

It return "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
"

I also tried to reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution.

> cat /proc/bus/input/devices

if you found something like this

N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" then do the next procedure

> apt-get install dkms

if cannot access dkms.
try

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin

Step 1: Download the following dkms package

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+attachment/3941591/+files/psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz

Step 2: Run the following commands in the download directory (or adjust the paths accordingly):

> sudo dkms ldtarball psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz
>
> sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c
>
> sudo rmmod psmouse
>
> sudo modprobe psmouse

ref.

https://superuser.com/questions/721417/elantech-touchpad-recognized-as-ps-2-mouse-ubuntu-13-10

http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2014/01/23/ubuntu-activate-multi-touch-on-elantech/

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=157091

https://superuser.com/questions/595818/add-usr-local-sbin-to-the-path-of-a-user

http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2014/01/23/ubuntu-activate-multi-touch-on-elantech/

Comment: Works but my right click is not working now what about you ?

Comment: as same as you T^T

Comment: Upgrade the kernel version, worked for me and remove this.

Comment: Ty, I will try to upgrade the kernel.