# Touchpad Lenovo Z50-70 - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my new laptop (Lenovo Z50-70).

Unfortunately, the touchpad is not working well.
Without any modifications/installs, just left and right click buttons are working (no scroll).

After doing this: [Cannot use twofinger on lenovo z5070 touchpad ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548755/cannot-use-twofinger-on-lenovo-z5070-touchpad-ubuntu-14-04)

My right click button has stopped working and scrolling is now working well.

How can I have my touchpad (left and right click buttons and scroll) working perfectly?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instructions on the following link about the [synaptic touch pad drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad). As most of the laptops ships with the synaptic touch pads.

Answer (score 0):

[Touchpad driver for g50-70](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1407785/+attachment/4309044/+files/psmouse-elantech-x551c-G50-70.tar.gz)

Download the file and then on terminal one by one line:

```
sudo dkms ldtarball psmouse-elantech-x551c-G50-70.tar.gz

sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c-G50-70

sudo rmmod psmouse

sudo modprobe psmouse
```